# Safe file extensions while uploading them to server

Tags: php

I'm creating a simple PHP cloud function for users in my panel project - user will be able to upload files via www to his account. I'm aware of some file extensions like .php and others.

What are the safe file extensions, that I can add as allowed? Like png, jpg, jpeg, txt, docx etc.

Is it worth to add this functionality to my project or should I just leave it, because dealing with security isn't so easy there?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, always store files in a non-public directory that's protected with an [htaccess](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess/) file. For good measure, just append a "safe" file extension (like ".dat") to every file before storing it. Also, be sure that you are checking that the user can't construct a request that would somehow allow them to fool your site into sending them data that they shouldn't have access to (such as other users' files, development and website-control files, etc). Validate everything - don't trust form input, cookies, or anything else originating from another system.

Answer (score 2):

There simply is **no such thing as a safe file extension**. A file extension primarily serves as a *type-hint* to the end-user, and has no real practical application for most software programs. Any exploitable security vectors directly related to file extensions stem from a larger issue, like poorly-configured file system permissions, web servers, or badly written code and as such cannot be mitigated through black listing of specific file extensions (*as far as remote file uploads are concerned*).

What most software programs, on NIX* based operating systems, typically rely on to identify a file *type*, are [magic MIME bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number). You can check the MIME type of a file in PHP using something like [`mime_content_type()`](http://php.net/mime-content-type) or [`finfo::file()`](http://php.net/function.finfo-file), instead.

However, this isn't, in and of itself, any measure of actual security. When we discuss how to make remote file uploads safe, we are speaking to a very broad array of security vectors that don't all revolve around the file being uploaded. Since file extensions are entirely user-supplied data, they cannot be trusted anyway and as such cannot possibly serve as a means for securing anything.